# import an argument from a function as a variable to another function

Tags: python, function, variables, import, arguments

Is there any way to import an argument from a function as a variable to another function?

For example:
untitled1.py

```
def fun1(a,b):
   x = a+b
   return x
```

and I want to pass the `a` as a variable to the following function which is another py file..
untitled2.py

```
def fun2(c):
    d=c/a
    return d
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: You could store "a" as global variable but there is probably a better way if you explain why you want that.

Comment: Have you tried using a closure and having your second function within your first function? Or returning both your result and that variable from function 1?

Comment: If you passed a to function 1 you already have a in your main function so you can pass it to function 2.

Comment: What's wrong with `fun2(a, c)`?

Comment: I am trying to do a report for the university and they impose for the second function to not have as argument the argument of the first function...the above is just an example of what i am trying ..is not the real functions

Comment: What exactly is the assignment? Is `fun2` supposed to be defined inside `fun1`?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the variable 'a' as global.

variable.py

```py
class A:
    value = None
```

untitled1.py

```py
def fun1(a,b):
   x = a.value+b
   return x
```

untitled2.py

```py
def fun2(c):
    d=c/a.value
    return d
```

where to call func1, func2

```py
A.value = 2
func1(A, 4)
func2(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`untitled1.py

def fun1(a,b):

```
   x = a+b
   return x,a
```

untitled2.py

import untitled1

def fun2(c):

```
var1,var2 = fun1(a,b)
d=c/var2
return d`
```